# Convert Spark Data frame to multiple list with one column as key

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Consider a Spark data frame *df* like this

```
+----+-------+----+----+
|bin|median|min|end|
+----+-------+----+----+
|   1|    0.0|   0|   0.5|
|   2|    1.0|   0.8|   1.7|
|   3|    2.0|   1.6|   2.5|
|   4|    4.0|   3.7|   4.7|
|   5|    6.0|   5.7|   6.3|
```

I would like to pull out each attribute/column as a separate dictionary/list with *bin* being key, meaning

```
median[1] = 0.0 #df[df.bin == 1]
median[key= 1,2,3,4,5] = [0.0,1.0,2.0,4.0,6.0]
min[key= 1,2,3,4,5] = [0,0.8,1.6,3.7,5.7]
```

I am thinking of something like mapping into rdd, how about something more "dataframe" manipulation ? Is there a way to pull out all the lists at the same time ?

```
median = {}
df.rdd.map(lambda row : median[row.bin] = row.median)
```

What is the answer if I want to pull out list instead of dictionary, assuming the bin will be numbered continuously from 1 ? How do we make sure keeping the order ? `.orderBy().collect()`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to `collect` your data anyway, the easiest way IMO to get the data in your desired format is via pandas.

You can call `toPandas()`, set the index to `bin`, and then call `to_dict()`:

```python
output = df.toPandas().set_index("bin").to_dict()
print(output)
#{'end': {1: 0.5, 2: 1.7, 3: 2.5, 4: 4.7, 5: 6.3},
# 'median': {1: 0.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 2.0, 4: 4.0, 5: 6.0},
# 'min': {1: 0.0, 2: 0.8, 3: 1.6, 4: 3.7, 5: 5.7}}
```

This will create a dictionary of dictionaries, where the outer key is the column name and the inner key is the bin. If you wanted separate variables, you can just extract from `output`, but don't use `min` as a variable name since it will stomp on `__builtin__.min`.

```python
median, min_, end = output['median'], output['min'], output['end']
print(median[1])
#0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach which provides support for both key and column filtering. The solution consists of two functions:

- `as_dict(df, cols, ids, key)`: returns data into a dictionary
- `extract_col_from_dict(dct, col, ids)`: extracts the column data from a dictionary

Initially let's extract the desired data into a dictionary from the given dataframe:

```
def as_dict(df, cols = [], ids = [], key = 0):
  key_idx = 0

  if isinstance(key, int):
    key_idx = key
    key = df.columns[key_idx]
  elif isinstance(key, str):
    key_idx = df.columns.index(key)
  else:
    raise Exception("Please provide a valid key e.g:{1, 'col1'}")

  df = df.select("*") if not cols else df.select(*[[key] + cols])

  if ids:
    df = df.where(df[key].isin(ids))

  return df.rdd.map(lambda x : (x[key_idx], x.asDict())).collectAsMap()
```

**Arguments:**

- *df*: the dataframe
- *cols*: the columns that you want to work with, *default* include all columns
- *ids*: in order to avoid collecting all the dataset on the driver you can filter based on this. This applies for the *key* column. *Default* include all records
- *key*: the key column, it can be string/int, *default* 0

Let's call the function with your dataset:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
[(1, 0.0, 0., 0.5),
(2, 1.0, 0.8, 1.7),
(3, 2.0, 1.6, 2.5),
(4, 4.0, 3.7, 4.7),
(5, 6.0, 5.7, 6.3)], ["bin", "median", "min", "end"])

dict_ = as_dict(df)
dict_
{1: {'bin': 1, 'min': 0.0, 'end': 0.5, 'median': 0.0},
 2: {'bin': 2, 'min': 0.8, 'end': 1.7, 'median': 1.0},
 3: {'bin': 3, 'min': 1.6, 'end': 2.5, 'median': 2.0},
 4: {'bin': 4, 'min': 3.7, 'end': 4.7, 'median': 4.0},
 5: {'bin': 5, 'min': 5.7, 'end': 6.3, 'median': 6.0}}

# or with filters applied
dict_ = as_dict(df, cols = ['min', 'end'], ids = [1, 2, 3])
dict_
{1: {'bin': 1, 'min': 0.0, 'end': 0.5},
 2: {'bin': 2, 'min': 0.8, 'end': 1.7},
 3: {'bin': 3, 'min': 1.6, 'end': 2.5}}
```

The function will map the records to *key/value pairs* where the value will be also a dictionary (calling row.asDict).

After calling as_dict function the data will be located on the driver and now you can extract the data that you need with the extract_col_from_dict:

```
def extract_col_from_dict(dct, col, ids = []):
  filtered = {}
  if ids:
    filtered = { key:val for key, val in dct.items() if key in ids }
  else:
    filtered = { key:val for key, val in dct.items() }

  return [d[col] for d in list(filtered.values())]
```

**Arguments:**

- *dct*: the source dictionary
- *col*: column to be extracted
- *ids*: more filtering, *default* all records

And the output of the function:

```
min_data = extract_col_from_dict(dict_, 'min')
min_data
[0.0, 0.8, 1.6, 3.7, 5.7]
```